# How can i take value of hyperlink in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview , i can access to value of cells but not the hyperlink one.
when i try to get it , i only get empty string. 5th cell is hyperlink cell.

```
    protected void GridView4_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)

        TableCell cell = GridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];
        string sid = cell.Text;
        string id = Session["id"].ToString();
        TableCell cell2 = GridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];
        string sid2 = cell2.Text;          


            TableCell cell3 = GridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5];
        string sid3 = cell3.Text;
```

and this is my hyper link:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="DosyaAdresi" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="dosyalar\{0}" DataTextField="DosyaAdresi" HeaderText="DosyaAdresi" DataTextFormatString="DosyaAdresi" Text="DosyaAdresi" >
```

i expect sid3 like "1531351.jpg" but returns "".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18189418/10466324    I hope you could do the rest man :)

Comment: Hi, when i try it i get the text name "Dosyaadi". not the value of Dosyaadi. Can you please help about it? @Tay

Comment: you mean NavigateUrl ? go ahed and use this property :)

Comment: I think im trying to get DataTextField or NavigateUrl  :) i just dont want to show adresses to user but want to use value

Comment: use DataTextField then :)

Comment: i am already using it :)  DataTextField="DosyaAdresi"

Answer (score 0):

Your table cell doesn't have any text, instead it has a HyperLink control, you should retrieve it and then getting it's text.

string sid3 =  ((HyperLink)GridView4.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;

Comment: Hi, when i try it i get the text name "Dosyaadi". not the value of Dosyaadi. Can you please help about it?

Comment: In a debugging session you can easily find out the HyperLink property you need. Cheers.